# How communicate between two DLLs loaded by same process without loading them again?

Tags: c++, dll, com

I want to communicate between two plug-ins in an application.
Both plug-ins are C++ COM DLLs. Let's call them DLL1 and DLL2.

In DLL1, I have created an instance of a COM class that loads the COM DLL.
From DLL2, I can create a similar instance of that COM class which may again load that COM DLL.

Basically, I don't want to load that COM DLL again from DLL2 and somehow get the handle of this COM DLL which is already loaded by DLL1.
Can I call a function present in COM DLL(which is loaded by DLL1) from DLL2 without again loading it?

The constraint here is, I don't want to load COM DLL from DLL2. It will be loaded by DLL1 and I just want to execute that COM DLL function from DLL2.

Comment: Why would Windows load a DLL twice in the same process? Is it getting unloaded inbetween? How did you determine that this happens? If possible, can you show code that loads "that COM DLL"?

Comment: If it's the same process, the DLL won't be loaded again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `LoadLibrary` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya):

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count. The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

and

> If the specified module is a DLL that is **not already loaded for the calling process**, the system calls the DLL's DllMain function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value. If DllMain returns TRUE, LoadLibrary returns a handle to the module. If DllMain returns FALSE, the system unloads the DLL from the process address space and LoadLibrary returns NULL.

So calling `LoadLibrary("XXX.dll")` twice in the same process will only result loading the library *once*, the second call should get the same module handle back.

Comment: The COM DLL gets loaded when an instance of the COM object is created from DLL1. Now in DLL2, how can I know if the COM DLL is already loaded before creating the COM object.

Comment: Why do you care? It is harmless to call `LoadLibrary` again.

Comment: I am creating a COM instance in DLL1 which calls COM DLL's Dllmain and loads it. Again, from DLL2 I am creating a COM instance with 'comInterfacePtr.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(COMModule));' I am not using 'LoadLibrary'. Now, in DLL2, I just want to know whether the COM DLL is already loaded.

Comment: Check with `GetModuleHandle`? I presume you have no ambitions for loose coupling so might as well check if the dll is loaded by name